# ¿Cómo agregar desviación estándar a gráfico en facetas?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, gráficas

Tengo el data frame:

```
datos_2 <- data.frame(fecha = seq.Date(ymd("2017-08-15"), ymd("2017-08-27"), length.out = 14), 
       temperatura = c(25.0, 26.7, 26.6, 25.2, 25.1, 27.6, 27.0, 28.8, 26.2, 24.3, 24.4, 24.8, 24.7, 26.3), 
       humedad_rel = c(88.8, 86.7, 86.1, 86.4, 86.9, 88.7, 89.1, 85.8, 90.9, 88.0, 85.7, 87.4, 84.9, 84.9),  
       fluctuacion_tronco = c(297.7, 278.9, 251.7, 231.3, 270.9, 346.4, 342.1, 331.7, 370.0, 283.5, 186.4, 255.6, 189.5, 193.0), 
       desv_est = c(37.2, 36.4, 34.1, 29.4, 37.1, 51.8, 42.1, 39.9, 41.7, 35.5, 23.2, 28.1, 26.6, 22.5))
```

Trabajando con el código:

```
 datos_2<- gather(data = datos_2, key = "variable", value = "valor", -fecha, -desv_est)

    datos_2 %>% 
  mutate(temporada = factor(ifelse(datos_2$fecha <= "2017-08-18", "Temporada 1", "Temporada 2")), 
         x = as.Date(ifelse(datos_2$fecha <= "2017-08-18", "2017-08-17", "2017-08-19"))) %>% 
  left_join(datos_2 %>% 
              group_by(variable) %>% 
              summarise(y = max(valor)), by = "variable") %>% 
  group_by(variable, temporada, x, y) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(variable, temporada, x, y) -> datos_anotaciones

ggplot(datos_2, aes(x = fecha, y = valor)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = datos_2$fecha, date_breaks = "2 days") + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y", 
             strip.position = "left") + 
  labs(x = "Fecha", 
       y = NULL, 
       title = "Contracción Diaria del Tronco (CDT) vs Factores", 
       subtitle = "Gráfico por día") + 
  theme_light() + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  geom_vline(linetype = "dotted", 
             size = 1.5, 
             colour = "red", 
             mapping = aes(xintercept = as.Date("2017-08-18"))) + 
  geom_text(data = datos_anotaciones, 
            mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = temporada))
```

Y obtengo el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-> Necesito agregar barras de error solamente en el gráfico de la primera faceta "fluctuación_tronco", la data para las barras de error es "desv_est". los otros dos gráficos no tienen dato para error, es posible? Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es posible, puedes resolverlo así:

```
  geom_errorbar(data=datos_2 %>%
                  filter(variable == 'fluctuacion_tronco'),
                aes(ymin=valor-desv_est, ymax=valor+desv_est)
                ) +
```

En este caso, el `geom_errorbar` tiene una fuente de datos distinta al del gráfico, y son los datos originales "filtrados" por la variable de interés.

Un resultado similar, pero usando la misma fuente de datos del gráfico, podría ser modificar `datos_2`:

```
datos_2 %>%
   mutate(desv_est = ifelse(variable == 'fluctuacion_tronco', desv_est, NA))
```

y finalmente:

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=valor-desv_est, ymax=valor+desv_est)) +
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!!